# Terminal timestamp text wrap, help me fix it

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

can someone help me fix the timestamp I added to my terminal ?
[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXiks.png)

[But everytime I use the up arrow key the text goes like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3HaV.png)

[or like this if I don't have a location set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNpK6.png)

Here's the line I added to my .bashrc :

export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -n $(tput setaf 154)[$(date +%H:%M:%S) AM\] "

Thanks again !

Comment: The primary terminal PROMPT is set by the variable PS1. Look here for possible  formatting of PS1 ; https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html ... don't use PROMPT_COMMAND to output prompt to terminal.

Comment: PROMPT_COMMAND is more useful when you want a multiline prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```bsh
PS1='\[$(tput setaf 154)\][$(date "+%H:%M:%S %p")]\[$(tput setaf 15)\]:\w \$ '
```

That's adding `\[...\]` around the tput output to allow bash to correctly calculate the width of the prompt. It uses single quotes to delay the evaluation of the command substitutions until the prompt is displayed

Note that PROMPT_COMMAND (and PS1) are *shell* variables and do not need to be exported into the environment of child processes.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works !